# How to add currency converter to my flutter to my e-commerce app linked to woocommerce

Tags: android, ios, flutter, woocommerce, e-commerce

I want to add a currency converter in an e-commerce flutter app I have it retrieving data from Woocommerce website, i don't need automatic conversion I would like to add it manually in WordPress and let the app retrieve it from the API